# JS - Как на странице заменить один тег на другой?

Tags: javascript

Надо заменить
`p` на `ans1`, `ans2` ... `ansN` скриптом

Из этого

```
<div class="entry">
  <p>Сломался</p>
  <p>Нет света</p>
  <p>Нет сигнала</p>
  <p>Сгорел</p>
  <p>Плохая погода</p>
  <p>Не заплатили</p>
</div>
```

В это

```
<div class="entry">
  <ans1>Сломался</ans1>
  <ans2>Нет света</ans2>
  <ans3>Нет сигнала</ans3>
  <ans4>Сгорел</ans4>
  <ans5>Плохая погода</ans5>
  <ans6>Не заплатили</ans6>
</div>
```

Comment: потрудитесь напечатать html буквами

Comment: Зачем скриптом? @Igor верно сказал, напишите все ручками

Comment: @lazytechwork не мой сайт,сам не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#container > p').forEach((el, num) => {
      el.outerHTML = `<ans${num + 1}>${el.innerHTML}</ans${num + 1}>`;
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Lorem.</p>
  <p>Reiciendis?</p>
  <p>Magni!</p>
  <p>Debitis.</p>
  <p>Cumque.</p>
  <p>Quibusdam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А как это можно запихнуть в var,что бы выдавал алертом?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replace() {
  var div = document.querySelector(".entry");
  var count = div.querySelectorAll("p").length;
  var str = div.innerHTML;
  for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    str = str.replace('<p>', `<ans${i}>`);
    str = str.replace('</p>', `</ans${i}>`);
  }
  div.innerHTML = str;
  
  console.log(div.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="replace()">Replace</button>
<div class="entry">
  <p>Сломался</p>
  <p>Нет света</p>
  <p>Нет сигнала</p>
  <p>Сгорел</p>
  <p>Плохая погода</p>
  <p>Не заплатили</p>
</div>
```